# How do I check which java instance method has been called to apply appropriate discount to the property?

Tags: java, oop

So, basically I have a Funpark class which has 3 activities. If user enrolls in 2 activities, then I want to apply 10% discount on totalPrice and if they apply to all 3 activities, I want to give 20% discount on totalPrice.

Here is my code for FunPark class:

```
public class FunPark {
    private final int climbWallPrice = 10;
    private final int trampoliningPrice = 12;
    private final int waterSlidesPrice = 15;

    public float getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    private float totalPrice = 0;

    private float applyDiscountTo(float applyTo, int discountInPercent) {

        float discount = (float) discountInPercent / 100;
        float discountValue = applyTo * discount;

        float discountedPrice = applyTo - discountValue;

        return discountedPrice;
    }

    public void climbWall() {
        if(totalPrice == trampoliningPrice || totalPrice == waterSlidesPrice) {
            totalPrice += climbWallPrice;
            totalPrice = applyDiscountTo(totalPrice, 10);
        }

        else if(totalPrice == trampoliningPrice + waterSlidesPrice) {
            totalPrice += climbWallPrice;
            totalPrice = applyDiscountTo(totalPrice, 20);
        }

        else {
            totalPrice = climbWallPrice;
        }
    }

    public void trampoline() {
        if(totalPrice == climbWallPrice || totalPrice == waterSlidesPrice) {
            totalPrice += trampoliningPrice;
            totalPrice = applyDiscountTo(totalPrice, 10);
        }

        else if(totalPrice == climbWallPrice + waterSlidesPrice) {
            totalPrice += trampoliningPrice;
            totalPrice = applyDiscountTo(totalPrice, 20);
        }

        else {
            totalPrice = trampoliningPrice;
        }
    }



    public void waterSlide() {
        if(totalPrice == climbWallPrice || totalPrice == trampoliningPrice) {
            totalPrice += waterSlidesPrice;
            totalPrice = applyDiscountTo(totalPrice, 10);
        }

        else if(totalPrice == climbWallPrice + trampoliningPrice) {
            totalPrice += waterSlidesPrice;
            totalPrice = applyDiscountTo(totalPrice, 20);
        }

        else {
            totalPrice = waterSlidesPrice;
        }
    }

}
```

The output I get is `15.0`

But, my expected result (in this case) is `37.6` (because of course the sum price for all three activities - 20% discount is `29.6`

Here is my calling code in the main class btw:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");

        FunPark park = new FunPark();

        park.trampoline();
        park.climbWall();
        park.waterSlide();

        System.out.println(park.getTotalPrice());
    }
}
```

So, could anyone please guide me in a direction on how should I go on about achieving the result? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code, to see what is going wrong?

Comment: @Jens Yes, I can see that the problem appears because I call the discount method in all three activities methods. But, I don't know of any other way on how I would achieve the desired output.

Comment: I don't think you can calculate the price "on the go", as the activities are being done. You have to calculate it in `getTotalPrice`, right? Otherwise the math doesn't work out.

Comment: @Sweeper but how? because how would I keep track of the activities added?

Comment: hint: think "shopping-cart" :)

Comment: Hold on, (10 + 12 + 15) * 0.8 is not 37.6...

Comment: @Sweeper yes sorry the expected result is 29.6. I'll update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work if you apply the discounts in each of the activity's methods. For example, consider the sequence:

```
park.trampoline();
park.climbWall();
park.waterSlide();
```

After `trampoline`, you add 12 to the total price which is initially 0 and apply no discounts. After `climbWall`, you add 12 (=22) and apply 10% discount, and get 19.8. Then after `waterSlide`, you add another 15 (=34.8) and apply a 20% discount, and the result is incorrectly 27.84.

You *could* potentially do it this way by "undoing" the discounts with more math, but I find that more counter-intuitive.

Better to just keep track of the activities. You can do this easily with an enum.

```
enum Activity {

    CLIMB_WALL(10),
    TRAMPOLINE(12), 
    WATER_SLIDE(15);
    private final int price;
    
    Activity(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Then you can use a list to record all the activities:

```
// in FunPark
private List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<>();

public void climbWall() {
    activities.add(Activity.CLIMB_WALL);
}

public void trampoline() {
    activities.add(Activity.TRAMPOLINE);
}

public void waterSlide() {
    activities.add(Activity.WATER_SLIDE);
}
```

The price can be calculated by iterating through the list:

```
public float getTotalPrice() {
    float total = 0;
    var uniqueActivities = new HashSet<Activity>();
    for (var activity : activities) {
        uniqueActivities.add(activity);
        total += activity.getPrice();
    }
    if (uniqueActivities.size() == 2) {
        total = applyDiscountTo(total, 10);
    } else if (uniqueActivities.size() == 3) {
        total = applyDiscountTo(total, 20);
    }
    return total;
}
```